# Send value from activity to its fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to send data from my activity class to its tab fragment, but in the fragment adapter it received no data and produced error nullPointerException.

here is my code

from activity

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
    String tenant = null;
    if ((bundle = receivedIntent.getExtras()) != null) {
        tenant = (String) bundle.get("tenant");
    }

    TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
    bundle.putString("tenant", tenant);
    tabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

to fragment

```
Bundle getTenant = this.getArguments();
    if(getTenant != null) {
        tenant = getTenant.getString("tenant");
        System.out.println("Tab fragment: " + tenant);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Tab fragment: null");
    }
```

pager adapter

```
case 0:
            TabFragment tabFragment = new TabFragment();
            tabFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return tabFragment;
```

Comment: I don't understand that why you want data to fragment pager adapter and if you want than declare pager adapter in activity which you are using to pass data. 
if you want to pass data into pager adapter than first of all pass data to pager adapter and after that pass that data to fragment using below code.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment do this

```
if(getArguments() != null) {
    tenant = getArguments().getString("tenant");
    System.out.println("Tab fragment: " + tenant);
}else {
    System.out.println("Tab fragment: null");
}
```

instead of

```
Bundle getTenant = this.getArguments();
if(getTenant != null) {
    tenant = getTenant.getString("tenant");
    System.out.println("Tab fragment: " + tenant);
}else {
    System.out.println("Tab fragment: null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

***Another way You are able to pass data using Interface like Below:***
1 step: I created public interface in my Activity and setter for it:

```
    Private OnAboutDataReceivedListener mAboutDataListener;
      public interface OnAboutDataReceivedListener {
        void onDataReceived(YourModelClass model);
    }

     public void setAboutDataListener(OnAboutDataReceivedListener listener) {
        this.mAboutDataListener = listener;
      }
```

2 step: I implemented this interface in my Fragment and set listener:

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseFragment implements YourBaseActivity.OnAboutDataReceivedListener

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mActivity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
            mActivity.setAboutDataListener(this);
        }
```

3 step: I overrided interface's method:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataReceived(YourClassModel model) {
    }
```